# Html and javascript in visual studio 2013

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

i have been working with visual studio for variety of projects for quite a while now, bu t i recently needed to develop a simple html5 webpage that will use some embedded or a seperate file of javascript, now i know there are asp.net projects which support stuff like that but i wanted to know is there a template or project type or something using which i can work purely with html and js only without having to deal with hell of asp.net configs and pages and all that? just simple html5 and js dev with intellisense and maybe a designer mode for css. i looked over internet and am unable to find an exact answer.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting from scratch you can go to File > New > Web Site and choose ASP.NET Empty Web Site. This will give you a very basic site, which has nothing but a Web.config file. You can then add all of your html, js, and css from there. You can also delete the Web.config file, but it is useful as it allows you to continue to use the debugger on your site.

Alternatively you can just start the project in windows explorer, setup the basic files and site directories, then you can go back into Visual Studio, and go to File > Open > Website and then locate the directory your site is in. This will just open the files and allow you to work on them like any other project.

These are the only ways I've seen so far, you may also be able to find project templates online but I haven't looked.

Also, if you're using Visual Studio in this way, then I recommend installing [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) it adds a lot of useful features.

Hope that helps.